# Rails 3 - Passing models to another controller & losing stylesheets on render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to build a simple content management system using Twitter's Bootstrap for a small site and I'm running into an issue with the views.

**Rails version is 3.0.10**

I want to allow the user to create their own pages so I have a **Pages** controller that has all your standard RESTful methods.  Since these can have crud applied to them, they can only be accessed by a logged-in administrator.

So... I have a **Public** controller that sets the **@pages** and **@page** instance variables and uses those to display them in the public Show view.

Here is the Public controller - pretty simple:

```
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def show
    @pages = Page.all
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])    
  end
```

The reason that there is a @pages instance variable on the 'index' method is because I have a welcome page that loads and I'm passing in @pages to populate the navigation elements dynamically:

```
    <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><%= link_to "Welcome", public_index_path, :class => 'active', :id => 'menu_home' %></li>

          <% @pages.each do |page| %>
             <li><%= link_to page.title, public_path(page) %></li>
          <% end %>           

          </ul>
   </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

The content of the Public controller's 'show' method (which contains an individual page) is passed into the `<%= yield %>` statement in the **applicaton.html.erb** file:

```
<div class="container">    

  <%= yield %>
  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>My site</p>
  </footer>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

So far, this is working fine.

**The problem is that when I click the link that takes me to the `public_path(page)` - I get the content as it should appear, but I lose all my styles.  I'm actually getting a 404 error on my stylesheets:**

[image]

All of these style sheets were loading in just fine on the http://localhost:3000/public page, but when it goes to http://localhost:3000/public/1 - that's when all the styles disappear.  But, they are both using the same layout.

Here is what the log file shows when the request is made:

```
Started GET "/public/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-03 21:14:49 -0600
  Processing by PublicController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mPage Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"
  [1m[36mPage Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
Rendered public/show.html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 51.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-03 21:14:50 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css"):


Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.0ms)


Started GET "/public/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-03 21:14:50 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/public/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css"):


Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)


Started GET "/public/stylesheets/elements.less" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-03 21:14:51 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/public/stylesheets/elements.less"):


Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (3.0ms)
```

**Thanks for having a look**

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  Your tag indicates ruby-on-rails-3, but as a general rule, stylesheets in rails 3.x should be part of the asset pipeline.

Comment: Rails 3.0.10.  What is unusual is that the stylesheets work just fine in the application layout on the main page, but on subsequent pages - using the same layout - the app can't find them.

Comment: Marc, I think the asset pipeline wasn't actually introduced until rails 3.1.0 so not in 3.0.10

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific about the rails version after Marc's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find my own answer...

The Rails helper **stylesheet_link_tag** was generating a relation attribute of type "stylesheet" when the Less css files needed a relation of type "stylesheet/less".

The fix was specifying the relation like this:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'elements.less', :rel => 'stylesheet/less' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main.less', :rel => 'stylesheet/less' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change path to your resource, something like that:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :public, :path => :my_public
```

This will give you routes

```
public_index GET  /my_public(.:format)          public#index
             POST /my_public(.:format)          public#create
new_public   GET  /my_public/new(.:format)      public#new
edit_public  GET  /my_public/:id/edit(.:format) public#edit
public       GET  /my_public/:id(.:format)      public#show
             PUT  /my_public/:id(.:format)      public#update
             DELETE /my_public/:id(.:format)    public#destroy
```

This way it will not mess up with requests to the static assets in `public` directory. But you may want to rename resource and controller instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Having a public resource, though, doesn't cause a conflict with the public folder that houses the styles and scripts.  Turns out it was a problem with the way the Less css files are called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bootstrap-saas gem, make sure you take out the "link href='assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css' rel='stylesheet'" tag out of your application.html.erb file, this will prevent the helper from generating the relation which results in a routing error.